# PDF Multiple Digital sign

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf, fpdi

I visit into a similar issue in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062014/tcpdf-multiple-signatures). Using FPDI and TCPDF I can sign a PDF document with a signature without problems, but when it comes to multiple signatures the previous signature remains unformatted and only the last signed is valid. Solution can you recommend me?, Thanks.

Comment: Tags tcpdf, fpdi added

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I was checking the latest version of the TCPDF code and see that setSignature() has a paramater called `$approval`. If it sets to `'A'` , the code does different processing for the digital signature and the parameter descriptions suggests it is for `incremental update` (i.e. @param $approval (string) Enable approval signature eg. for PDF incremental update). I haven't seen that value being mentioned in the documentation. Try using that for additional signatures after the first one.

[image: setSignature() method]

[image: putSignature() method]

Or use a paid solution like PDFTron, which supports PDF

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/php/DigitalSignaturesTest

**ORIGINAL VERSION**

This can only be done through `incremental update`, which allows appending new section without modifying the original document that's been signed previously. See section 7.5.6 in PDF format spec:

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

TCPDF does not support incremental update. See the help forum question:

https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/8cf24d19/

You need to use a library that supports incremental update. Once such library is [SignPDF from NodeJS world](https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf). Here is the issue ticket that's been [discussed multiple signatures](https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/issues/25).  Maybe you can have this as a back-end service just for applying signatures for this portion of your app.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212273/1729265

Comment: was this helpful ?